# openstack stack show <stack name>

Tags: openstack

Newton user guide for openstack [newton](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/user-guide/cli-create-and-manage-stacks.html) mentions the command `show` for a `stack`. Example: `openstack stack show <stack_name>`.

However, latest docs [stein](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/stein/cli/command-list.html) don't mention anything about this command. How can I show stack info in latest openstack/openstackclient release (stein at the moment of writing this question)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That same functionality is still there. Check out https://docs.openstack.org/python-heatclient/stein/cli/stack.html

If the command is missing in your environment, then you probably just need to install `python-heatclient`. It is not available by default with the unified openstack client.

Comment: Is there any trick on how to use it? I have python-heatclient installed, but stack subcommand is still not available :(

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have not outdated version of python-openstackclient
just install it with pip in venv and then install python-heatclient from pip as well